# Using awk with Operations on Variables

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I'm trying to write a Bash script that reads files with several columns of data and multiplies each value in the second column by each value in the third column, adding the results of all those multiplications together.

For example if the file looked like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
genome      1           30          500
genome      2           27          500
genome      3           83          500
...
```

The script should multiply 1*30 to give 30, then 2*27 to give 54 (and add that to 30), then 3*83 to give 249 (and add that to 84) etc..

I've been trying to use awk to parse the input file but am unsure of how to get the operation to proceed line by line. Right now it stops after the first line is read and the operations on the variables are performed.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
for file in fileone filetwo
do
    set -- $(awk '/genome/ {print $2,$3}' $file.hist)
    var1=$1
    var2=$2
    var3=$((var1*var2))
    total=$((total+var3))

    echo var1 \= $var1
    echo var2 \= $var2
    echo var3 \= $var3
    echo total \= $total
done
```

I tried placing a "while read" loop around everything but could not get the variables to update with each line. I think I'm going about this the wrong way!

I'm very new to Linux and Bash scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

That's because awk reads the entire file and runs its program on each line. So the output you get from `awk '/genome/ {print $2,$3}' $file.hist` will look like

```
1 30
2 27
3 83
```

and so on, which means in the bash script, the `set` command makes the following variable assignments:

```
$1 = 1
$2 = 30
$3 = 2
$4 = 27
$5 = 3
$6 = 83
```

etc. But you only use `$1` and `$2` in your script, meaning that the rest of the file's contents - everything after the first line - is discarded.

Honestly, unless you're doing this just to learn how to use bash, I'd say just do it in awk. Since awk automatically runs over every line in the file, it'll be easy to multiply columns 2 and 3 and keep a running total.

```
awk '{ total += $2 * $3 } ENDFILE { print total; total = 0 }' fileone filetwo
```

Here `ENDFILE` is a special address that means "run this next block at the end of each file, not at each line."

If you *are* doing this for educational purposes, let me say this: the only thing you need to know about doing arithmetic in bash is that you should never do arithmetic in bash :-P Seriously though, when you want to manipulate numbers, bash is one of the *least* well-adapted tools for that job. But if you really want to know, I can edit this to include some information on how you could do this task primarily in bash.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It's actually a small part of a larger bash script so I was trying to keep everything together just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `awk` is in general better suited for this kind of work, but if you are curious what a pure `bash` implementation would look like:

```
for f in file1 file2; do
    total=0
    while read -r _ x y _; do
        ((total += x * y))
    done < "$f"
    echo "$total"
done
```